# is there a way in Ag-Grid to have a different order for Columns inside toolpanel compared to Columns in the grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to find a solution to have a different order for the Coluns inside the toolpanel compared to the ones from the grid-table, for ex. I want the columns in the toolpanel to be sorted alphabetically in `asc` order and the ones in the grid-table by
their `hide` property.

I've set up the `suppressSyncLayoutWithGrid: true,` so the toolpanel is not synced with changes from the grid-table, because I want to push a column that becomes visible to the end of the grid (not displaying them alphabetically - by sorting the columns by their `hide` property) but keeping the columns order in the toolpanel alphabetical